# Subsequent jobs in gitlab-ci

Tags: gitlab-ci

Is there any way to run jobs from the stage in subsequent order? I've tried to do it with dependecies

```
job1:
    stage:deploy
...
job2:
    stage:deploy
dependencies:
    - job1
```

but it gives me an error "dependency job1 is not defined in prior stages".
Is there any workaround?

Comment: also tried 
 
    dependecies:
        - :job1
but result is same

Answer (score 29, accepted):

No. This is not possible by design. You will have to define more [stages](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/#stages).

As the [stages](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/#stages) docs describe:

> 1. Jobs of the same stage are run in parallel.

Comment: This doesn't stop the stage2 jobs to be triggered, can we somehow enforce that stage1 is run first till that stage2 is blocked. Only after stage1 is successfully completed, stage2 should be available to run either manually or automatically which we can specify in rules.

Answer (score 4):

It might become possible at some point in the future (as of January 2021). [Progress is being tracked here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/30632)

Answer (score 3):

You might have found out the answer by now, but still answering for future audiences coming to post when facing similar issue.

The error itself says "dependency job1 is not defined in prior stages", in your example both jobs having same name i.e "stage: deploy".

so that is the reason its not picking up the dependencies rule, also with new gitlab version, need clause can be used now.

```
Job1:
  Stage: A
Job2:
  Stage: B
  needs: ["Job1"]
```

This way, Job2 will get dependent on Job1